# What is the difference between PyCharm and PyCharm Edu

Tags: python, pycharm

Pycharm https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=windows

Pycharm https://www.jetbrains.com/edu-products/download/#section=pycharm-edu

What is the difference? Which is better for python beginners? (I am not new to programming, just relatively new to python)

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/pycharm-educational.html

Comment: PyCharm proper is a commercial product -- it includes some commercial-only features. PyCharm Edu is an open-source product -- anything that would otherwise be exclusive to paying customers isn't there. The extra features mentioned in jakub's link can also be installed on top of a different PyCharm edition.

Comment: BTW, note also that requests for product recommendations are explicitly off-topic here -- see the "some questions are still off-topic" list at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: You could also use Intellij community with the Python plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pycharm edu is used by teachers, from what I know to well teach and normal Pycharm is just used by regular people. So I would suggest you try Pycharm community edition first.
Sorry for broken english, i'm not a native speaker.
If this doesn't help you I suggest you look on the official site of pycharm.